# Is <? extends ...> exclusivity of method parameters?

Tags: java

Let's say I have two classes `A` and `B` which extends `A`. With the following method I can print a `Collection` of `A` or something extending `A`:

```
private static void print(Collection<? extends A> collection) {

    for (A element : collection) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }

}
```

It's great, I can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<A> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add(new A());
    l1.add(new B());
    print(l1);

    List<B> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l2.add(new B());
    l2.add(new B());
    print(l2);

}
```

Now my question is why in my method `main` (or somewhere else) I can write this

```
List<? extends A> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
```

but not this

```
l3.add(new A());
l3.add(new B());
```

I do understand why I can not add an instance of `A` or `B` in `l3`. But why the first statement which seems useless is authorized ?

**EDIT**

I ask with another words because I think my question is misunderstood.

What can I do with my empty list `List<? extends A> l3 = new ArrayList<>();` ? I know it's not possible to add anything because the type of the list is unknown.

Answer (score 6):

`List<? extends A> l3` means that `l3` *might be* a `List<A>` or it *might be* a `List<B>`.  `<? extends A>` means the compiler doesn't know and cannot safely assume any more than that.

Since it *might be* `List<B>`, `l3.add(new A())` is not safe.  The List would be corrupt, since it would not truly contain only instances of B.

Comment: It might even be `List<C>`, where `C` is another class extending `A`. So also `add(new B())` is not safe.

Comment: So it does not make any sense to write `List<? extends A> l3 = new ArrayList<>();` as it's not usable later ?

Comment: It is usable.  You just can't add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't covariant and "? extends A" is not A. So you can't do:

```
List<? extends A> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new A());
```

for the same reasons you can't do:

```
List<B> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new A());
```

nor:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new Object());
```

Comment: I know I can't do that. My question is why can I write `List<? extends A> l3 = new ArrayList<>();` whereas what you mentioned is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in `GENERICS`, The Type of `A` and `B` are not known until runtime. So Java can't instantiate them.

For more please read *[Oracle Generics Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/)*