# Java abstract class generic method parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I'm running into a problem with java abstract classes and generic functions. The implementation is a node class in a graph for Dijkstra's algorithm.

```
public abstract class Node {

    float distance;
    Node parent;

    public void relax(Node parent, Edge edge, PriorityQueue<? extends Node> priorityQueue) {
        if (this.distance > parent.distance + edge.weight){
            this.distance = parent.distance + edge.weight;
            this.parent = parent;
            priorityQueue.remove(this);
            priorityQueue.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the line:

> priorityQueue.add(this);

Because **this** references the Node class (which is abstract) it cannot be added to the priority queue and should in fact be of type **?** (the subclass of node) denoted in **? extends Node**. How to I reference this subclass type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513926/is-extends-exclusivity-of-method-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. I see two variants. Either you will use one type of subclass of a node and then you can write something like:

```
public <T extends Node> void relax(T parent, Edge edge, PriorityQueue<T> priorityQueue) {
    if (this.distance > parent.distance + edge.weight){
        this.distance = parent.distance + edge.weight;
        this.parent = parent;
        priorityQueue.remove(this);
        priorityQueue.add((T) this);
    }
}
```

Or you want to just use different types of nodes and mix and match them but then the type for queue will be just `PriorityQueue<Node>`.

Comment: You understood my problem just right (sorry for lack of detail). The idea is having multiple kind of nodes in my graph (street crossings ect.) and have use the same relax function.

Your solution works. However my IDE (IntelliJ) is saying "suspecious call" and "unchecked cast". Any way to improve this?

Comment: Idea is right to complain. There is no guarantee and you must know what you are doing. If you know that only nodes of certain type will be used in the same context you can just suppress the warning with @SuppressWarning annotation. Though you wrote 'multiple kinds of nodes use same relax function'. Then either you will calculate distance between say just crossings and then you can use my first suggestion or between different node types and then the you should have just PriorityQueue<Node> since there won't be single type of node.

Comment: Also some related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078814/designing-interface-for-hierarchical-entity