# Designing interface for hierarchical entity

Tags: java, interface, java-8, hierarchical, default-method

I have to design an interface for hierarchical entity:

```
interface HierarchicalEntity<T extends HierarchicalEntity<T>> {
    T getParent();
    Stream<T> getAncestors();
}
```

It's quite easy to implement **default** `getAncestors()` method in terms of `getParent()` in such a way that the former would return `Stream` of all the ancestors.

Implementation example:

```
default Stream<T> getAncestors() {
    Stream.Builder<T> parentsBuilder = Stream.builder();
    T parent = getParent();
    while (parent != null) {
        parentsBuilder.add(parent);
        parent = parent.getParent();
    }
    return parentsBuilder.build();
}
```

But I need to also include `this` into the stream, and here a problem appears. 
The following line is not correct because `this` is of type `HierarchicalEntity`, not `T`:

```
parentsBuilder.add(this); // type mismatch!
```

How can I redesign the interface in order to make `getAncestors()` include `this` into the result?

Comment: Unfortunately this will never be fully type safe. Java doesn't have a self-referential type syntax. I can create a `class Fake implements HierarchicalEntity<SomeOtherType>` and your `getAncestors` will presumably fail with a `ClassCastException` eventually.

Comment: Got the point. Maybe some redesign could be applied to the whole interface.

Comment: Just cast `this` to `T` and add it to the stream builder

Comment: @federico-peralta-schaffner Possible option, but there is a problem with case described by Sotirios Delimanolis above. Seems that there is no type safe way to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Aliaxander True, there's no way about it. I think it would be safe to assume the cast is valid if the hierarchy is used correctly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a recurring problem when creating self-referential types. In the base type (or interface), you can’t enforce that `this` will be assignment compatible with `T`.

Of course, you can perform an unchecked cast of `this` to `T` if you are confident that all subtypes will fulfill that constraint. But you have to perform this unchecked cast whenever you need a `this` reference as `T`.

The better solution is to add an abstract method like

```
/**
    All subtypes should implement this as:

    public T myself() {
        return this;
    }
 */
public abstract T myself();
```

Then, you can use `myself()` instead of `this` whenever you need a self-reference as `T`.

```
default Stream<T> getAncestors() {
    Stream.Builder<T> parentsBuilder = Stream.builder();
    for(T node = myself(); node != null; node = node.getParent()) {
        parentsBuilder.add(parent);
    }
    return parentsBuilder.build();
}
```

Of course, you can’t enforce that subclasses correctly implement `myself()` as `return this;`, but at least, you can easily verify whether they do at runtime:

```
assert this == myself();
```

This reference comparison is a very cheap operation and, if `myself()` is correctly implemented as invariably returning `this`, HotSpot can prove in advance that this comparison will always be `true` and elide the check completely.

The drawback is that each specialization will have to have this redundant implementation of `myself() { return this; }`, but on the other hand, it’s completely free of unchecked type casts. The alternative is to have an non-`abstract` declaration of `myself()` in the base class as `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T myself() { return (T)this; }` to limit the unchecked operation to a single place for the type hierarchy. But then, you can’t verify whether `this` really is of type `T`…

Answer (score 2):

As @SotiriosDelimanolis said, there's no way fully enforce this. But if you're willing to assume the interface is being used as designed, you can assume that `this` is an instance of `T` and simply cast it:

```
parentsBuilder.add((T)this);
```

If you want to avoid casting, you can add a method to be overridden in the subclass:

```
interface HierarchicalEntity<T extends HierarchicalEntity<T>> {
    T getParent();
    T getThis();
    default Stream<T> getAncestors() {
        // ...
        parentsBuilder.add(getThis());
        // ...
    }
}

class Foo extends HierarchicalEntity<Foo> {
    // ...
    @Override
    public Foo getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now we can get `this` in a typesafe manner, but there's no guarantee that `getThis()` has been implemented correctly. It's possible for it to return any instance of `Foo`. So, pick your poison I guess.

Comment: @Aliaxander If it's an option to use a common abstract class, you can create a constructor `AbstractEntity(T thisObj)` and have the subclasses call `super(this)` so you don't have to implement `getThis()` on each subclass. Still not elegant, but I don't know if there is an elegant solution.

Comment: You can't use `this` in an explicit constructor invocation, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Adding `this` fails because a `HierarchicalEntity<T>` is not necessarily a `T`; it could be an unknown subtype.  However, a `T` is always a `HierarchicalEntity<T>` as you've declared it that way.

Change the return type of `getAncestors` and of the `Stream.Builder` from `T` to `HierarchicalEntity<T>`, which will allow you to add `this`.

```
default Stream<HierarchicalEntity<T>> getAncestors() {
    Stream.Builder<HierarchicalEntity<T>> parentsBuilder = Stream.builder();
    T parent = getParent();
    while (parent != null) {
        parentsBuilder.add(parent);
        parent = parent.getParent();
    }
    parentsBuilder.add(this);
    return parentsBuilder.build();
}
```

You may wish to declare `getParent` to return a `HierarchicalEntity<T>` also for consistency.

Comment: But OP wants a stream of `T`.

Comment: @shmosel That is the current interface design, but there is no such explicit statement by the OP.

Comment: @rgettman actual type for `T` is supposed to have some methods that aren't defined in `HierarchicalEntity`, so code like `getAncestors().map(ActualType::foo)` becomes invalid.

Comment: @rgettman I would assume that the design indicates OP's requirements, unless explicitly stated otherwise. And given the interface as it's defined, it would be pretty useless to have a stream of `HierarchicalEntity`.