# Forcing class to implement parametrized interface

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have the following class / interface hierarchy:

```
interface BaseView {
    //some base view methods
}

interface BasePresenter<V extends BaseView> {
    void bindView(V view);
}
```

This is quite simple so far, but I am building on top of it:

```
interface GenericView extends BaseView {
    //some generic view methods
}

interface GenericPresenter<V extends GenericView> extends BasePresenter<V> {
    //some generic presenter methods
}
```

Let's now head to implementation of GenericView:

```
abstract class GenericViewImpl<V extends GenericView, P extends GenericPresenter<V>> extends BaseViewImpl implements GenericView {

    protected P presenter;

    void onLifecycleCreationEventCalled() {
        presenter.bindView((V) this); //on this line I have to do an unchecked cast to V in order to make it work
    }
}
```

These `GenericView` and `GenericPresenter` have multiple methods inside + they have multiple, specified implementations.

My question is: how should I change the class hierarchy to avoid that unchecked cast?

Comment: Could you include method signature of `bindView()`?

Comment: Why can't it be `void bindView(BaseView view)`? IMO, it seems like you are overusing generics quite a bit.

Comment: Each implementation on presenter performs different operation on matching view. If I pass `BaseVew` in `bindView` method then I would have to perform casting in each specific presenter.

Comment: Do you mean that you do `instance of` checks? If yes, then there is no need for generics in this case.

Comment: Using the implementation form above I do not do instanceof checks since java forces the right types. If I remove the V parameter from `BasePresenter` as per your suggestion then I would have to cast views in each `BasePresenter` implementation. Since there are lot of these implementations this would be highly undesirable.

Comment: But do you then call the same method/s on each implementation?

Comment: No, each implementation has a set of common methods from `BaseView` and some specific methods from specific implementation. For example there is a `LetterBoxView` which has additional methods called only by `LetterBoxPresenter`.

Comment: You can not enforce that subclasses match `V`. The best you can do, is to enforce the implementation of an `abstract` method returning `V`, supposed to be implemented as `return this;` by subclasses. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112903/2711488)…